# need help making a dictionary

Tags: python, list, object, dictionary

Im still new to python and trying to teach myself and at the same time tying to make make a FIFA 14 autobuyer. Ive been working with an already made Library https://github.com/Fire30/Fifa14Client

What I'm trying to do is make a dictionary out of the information I get when searching for a specific card

The function used to search for a card is in WebAppFunctioner.py file and is

```
def search(self, type="player", lev="gold", pos="CAM", num=1, team="101059",
               macr="", micr="", minb="", nat="", maxb="",
               playStyle="", leag="", start=50, cat="",
               definitionId="", maskedDefId=""):
        the_url = self.TRANSFER_URL % (self.platform_string,type, lev, pos, num, team,      macr, micr, minb, nat, maxb,
                                       playStyle, leag, start, cat, definitionId, maskedDefId)
        r = requests.post(the_url, headers=self.get_headers('GET'))
        try:
            json = r.json()
        except:
            raise BadRequestException("Could not complete search. No JSON object could be decoded")
        if 'auctionInfo' in  json:
            card_list = json['auctionInfo']
            return [Card.Card(card_dict) for card_dict in card_list]
        elif 'code' in json:
            raise FUTErrorCodeException("Could not get complete search.",json)
```

when I call function, print(func.search()), it makes a list of objects and prints each object in the terminal. Each object has a bunch of information in it and I am trying to take all the information and store it an a dictionary. I think that Card.py has exactly what I need except I dont really understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If the request is in fact valid the function should return a list of card dictionaries.

`return [Card.Card(card_dict) for card_dict in card_list]` is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which returns one or more of the results of card_dict (presumably the return value is a dict object) for each card that was in the auctionInfo json.

You shouldn't be expecting a dictionary back, but rather a list of dictionaries. If there is some unique identifier you could edit the code to be

```
    if 'auctionInfo' in  json:
        card_list = json['auctionInfo']
        return {some_unique_id: Card.Card(card_dict) for card_dict in card_list}
```

Edit: I had curly braces arount the some_unique_id k:v pair, that would have broken it.

Alternative: leave the function as is and handle it on the other side and just do a quick comprehension like:

`{card.unique_id_thing:card for card in search()}`